# Editing foreign keys in django-forms

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I recently got into django and django forms.

What i'm trying to do is make a form where my foreign key is editable. (a form of the other model where my foreign key is refering to inside a form).

so lets say I have these models

```
class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Model1(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(Model2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # other fields
```

When you render the form for Model1, the foreign key must be editble aswell.

I'm wondering if anything like this is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with some custom handling in your form - theres probably a nicer way to do this but here is how I would do it:

In forms.py

```
class Model1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    type = forms.CharField(label='Name')

    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = ['value', 'type']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        obj, created = Model2.objects.get_or_create(
            name=self.cleaned_data['type']
        )
        self.cleaned_data['type'] = obj.id
        return super().save(commit)
```

Also note that you shouldn't use `type` as a variable name.

Comment: Finally figured it out, I indeed had to overwrite the save method. but also do some handling in my view aswell. Anyway, this was the first step to solve problem and helped me a lot in figuring it out. Thanks! PS: py variable wasn't named type it was just for the example :)

Comment: Nice, glad to hear you solved it. Consider answering your own question with the solution you found to help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) for `Model1`'s `type` field:

```
class Model1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Model2.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        field = '__all__'
```

This will give you a selection of `Model2` objects to be used as the foreign key.

Comment: What if one wanted to filter `queryset`. Let's say `Model12` has a `belongs_to` field and one wants to filter the `queryset`by `request`'s user value?